# PHP - Passing Variables in 3 forms - Step1, Step2 and Step3

Tags: php, forms, variables, contacts

**I'm trying to create a form with 3 steps.**
1. Filling in the information.
2. Confirmation of information in 1 step.
3. Send email

Whenever I submits the confirmation form, I will receive an email without contents I filled in in Form 1.

Here are the codes:

### index.php

```
<?php
<form id="entry" action="confirm.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="school" id="school" />
<input type="submit" value="Next Step">
</form>
?>
```

### confirm.php

```
<?php
<form id="entry" action="thankyou.php" method="post">
<? echo $_POST["school"] ?>
</form>
?>
```

### thankyou.php

```
<?php
$subject = "Subject";
mail("YourEmail@gmail.com", $subject, $_POST["school"], "From: Testing" );
?>
```

Any help with be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, and what's the question?

Comment: Remove step two, step 3 should be in the file confirm.php

Comment: Okay, I can write the code for you.  I charge $30/hour with at least one hour paid up-front.  Do you have Paypal?

Comment: `$_POST("school"]`  should be `$_POST["school"]`.

Comment: @Chibuzo Yes, I have tried it and it works perfectly without step2, but what i want is people to see the results before submitting the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form 3 is incorrect, should be:
`mail("YourEmail@gmail.com", $subject, $_POST["school"], "From: Testing" );`
$_POST["school"].

Comment: When I say confirm form I mean a preview page for seeing the results of Form1